# Pass an array from JavaScript to PHP then back to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I need to pass an array from one page to a PHP page to get it to write it to a file, then another page has to access that file an array in the second page.

So far i have an array in JavaScript loaded with all the info I need:

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'woepanel.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: vars,
     });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$datap = array(json_decode($_POST['data']));
file_put_contents('var.txt', print_r($datap, true));
?>
```

As for the page pulling I'm unsure on how to accomplish this..

Comment: So what exactly is you problem passing the array to php, writing the file in php, accessing the file written by php from the second webpage or all three?

Comment: If you want to store it for a little while, then reuse it with JS, you're going to have to make a second AJAX call to get the contents via PHP, JS can't read the file you saved on the server. Just a quick tip to, if you're going to just store it for later usage what you could do is save it as JSON, parse it back to jquery to decode it, you don't need to convert it to an array with what you seem to want to do.

Comment: i cant get the array to pass to php and write it to a file

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use proper JSON both ways, i.e. you need to `stringify` the JSON before sending it, as otherwise it would be passed as a regular URL param, so:

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'woepanel.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(vars),
 });
```

php:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the array contains the "data"-key?
Try this

```
$.ajax({
url: 'woepanel.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
data: {
    "data" : vars
  },
});
```